# Pytorch unet semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have a Tensorflow v1 version of a unet which trains really nicely using SGD and a learning rate of 0.05.

I have rewritten the network in Pytorch as I want to expose some functionality which is not as easy in Tensorflow.

My model consistently predicts an empty mask so I have tried to make the model overfit to one image.

It is possible to overfit to one example image to predict one mask, but it only works with Adam, a learning rate of 0.0005 and 1000 epochs. My old model can do it in 10 epochs or so.

I can't see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong. I must be doing something incorrectly as this is a trivial problem which should require little tuning.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import transforms

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
torch.manual_seed(42)

class DoubleConv(nn.Module):
    """(convolution => [BN] => ReLU) * 2"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, relu=True):
        super().__init__()
        if relu:
            self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
            )
        else:
            self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.double_conv(x)


class Down(nn.Module):
    """Downscaling with maxpool then double conv"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxpool_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool_conv(x)


class Up(nn.Module):
    """Upscaling then double conv"""

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, bilinear=True, relu=True):
        super().__init__()

        # if bilinear, use the normal convolutions to reduce the number of channels
        if bilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels // 2, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=2, stride=2)

        self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels, relu=relu)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.up(x1)
        # input is CHW
        diffY = torch.tensor([x2.size()[2] - x1.size()[2]])
        diffX = torch.tensor([x2.size()[3] - x1.size()[3]])

        x1 = F.pad(x1, [diffX // 2, diffX - diffX // 2,
                        diffY // 2, diffY - diffY // 2])
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        return self.conv(x)


class OutConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(OutConv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)


class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes, bilinear=True):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.bilinear = bilinear

        self.inc = DoubleConv(n_channels, 64)
        self.down1 = Down(64, 128)
        self.down2 = Down(128, 256)
        self.down3 = Down(256, 512)
        self.down4 = Down(512, 512)
        self.up1 = Up(1024, 256, bilinear)
        self.up2 = Up(512, 128, bilinear)
        self.up3 = Up(256, 64, bilinear)
        self.up4 = Up(128, 64, bilinear)
        self.outc = OutConv(64, n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.inc(x)
        x2 = self.down1(x1)
        x3 = self.down2(x2)
        x4 = self.down3(x3)
        x5 = self.down4(x4)
        x = self.up1(x5, x4)
        x = self.up2(x, x3)
        x = self.up3(x, x2)
        x = self.up4(x, x1)
        logits = self.outc(x)
        return logits

def decode_segmap(image, num_classes=3):

  label_colors = np.array([(128, 0, 0),
               (0, 128, 0), (0, 0, 128)])

  r = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
  g = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
  b = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)

  for l in range(0, num_classes):
    idx = image == l
    r[idx] = label_colors[l, 0]
    g[idx] = label_colors[l, 1]
    b[idx] = label_colors[l, 2]

  rgb = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=2)
  return rgb


def load_batch(batch_size):
    rotated_frame = Image.open('0test.png')
    rotated_gt = Image.open('0label.png')

    trf = transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize(mean = [0.2455],  std = [0.2684])])

    rotated_frame = trf(rotated_frame).unsqueeze(0)

    trf = transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.ToTensor()])
    rotated_gt = trf(rotated_gt).unsqueeze(0)

    rotated_frame = torch.mean(rotated_frame, 1).unsqueeze(1)
    rotated_gt = torch.mean(rotated_gt, 1).unsqueeze(1)

    return rotated_frame.to(device), rotated_gt.type(torch.long).to(device).squeeze(1)


net = UNet(1, 3)
net.to(device=device)

# Loss
#optimizer = optim.RMSprop(net.parameters(), lr=0.005, weight_decay=1e-8)
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.0005)
#optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.0005)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Load data
rotated_frame, rotated_gt = load_batch(1)
print(rotated_frame.shape)
print(rotated_gt.shape)

# Train
epochs = 1000
losses = [] 
for epoch in range(epochs):
    predicted = net(rotated_frame)
    loss = criterion(predicted, rotated_gt)
    losses.append(loss)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print('Epoch {}/{} Loss: {}'.format(epoch, epochs, loss))

output = torch.argmax(predicted.squeeze(), dim=0).detach().cpu().numpy()

a, b = np.min(output), np.max(output)
print('Predicted: min: {} max: {}'.format(a, b))
print(output.shape)
rgb = decode_segmap(output)
plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.savefig('predicted_argmaxed.png')

gt = rotated_gt.squeeze().detach().cpu().numpy()
a, b = np.min(gt), np.max(gt)
print('Gt: min: {} max: {}'.format(a, b))
rgb = decode_segmap(gt)
plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.savefig('gt_argmaxed.png')
```

Sample images are here:

[image: 0test.png]
[image: 0label.png]

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any BN in you DoubleConv. It is a possible culprit.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use Categorical Crossentropy here? If you want Binary Crossentropy then use `BCELoss`.

Comment: If you want to see float images in decode_segmap output (your output example image seems not to be binary). If so use sigmoid function in each channel. 
Then to debug, dump its values and check if the images are complete zero (or ones) or have some float value. You may need to remove argmax with predicted to get actual net output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `CrossEntropyLoss` did you try adding weights for the classes?

```py
weights = torch.tensor([0.75, 1], dtype=torch.float)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=weights,
                                      reduction='none').to(device)
```

If your model is producing an empty mask (a white one for example) in theory it's minimizing the loss, since having a totally white image seems to be the class that is more prominent, depending on the amount of classes you have try to add more weight to the borders class.

The weights you see there I used when I was doing binary classification when a class was like 70% and the other 30%.

Otherwise BN as Natt mentioned could also help. Your learning rate also seems a bit too low.

**Edit**:
Just for clarification, from the docs:

```
weight (Tensor, optional) – a manual rescaling weight given to each class. If given, has to be a Tensor of size C
```

```
reduction (string, optional) – Specifies the reduction to apply to the output: 'none' | 'mean' | 'sum'. 'none': no reduction will be applied, 'mean': the sum of the output will be divided by the number of elements in the output, 'sum': the output will be summed. Note: size_average and reduce are in the process of being deprecated, and in the meantime, specifying either of those two args will override reduction. Default: 'mean'
```